# Multithread issue in JBoss 7

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, jboss7.x

I have got a problem (or doubt) about multithreading in jboss 7. My situation is more or less simillar to situation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932083/jboss-java-ee-container-and-an-executorservice):I have got piece of code that is running in many threads and now I have to move it to jboss server. Only thing that is different is that I don't use EJB, just spring+hibernate. So my question is: should I follow the same steps as was written in the answer or there is any other way that I can create many threads? (I was exploring jboss and there was some place to configure thread factory and thread pools and I don't know if it is tool that I can use in my app)

Comment: youre moving to jboss yet you dont use EJB? why move to jboss then?!

Comment: so it will be a difference if I will use web container as tomcat? Then I can create additional threads?

Comment: Ok thanks, if you could post this as an answer, I will mark it as solution :)

Comment: ok, posted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, not really. its "illegal" to create threads in Java EE and under the servlet specifcation. the link you pointed to it the easiest way to do threading under a web/Java EE container - use @Asynchronous. note that you can return a Future from such a method if you want to wait for the results