# Design of parallel computing application with java web/Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, parallel-processing, web-container

My question is related to my other question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123516/multithread-issue-in-jboss-7).

I would like to know what will be the best approach (or any) to deal with very complicated calculation problems that can be run parallely in java web applications? 
In my previous question there was stated that due to Java EE/web java specifications it is strictly forbiden to create and use your own threads (it is, actualy, possible but requires to use tricks and it is not advised to do that).

I was thinking about it and, since all web aplications are multithreads as themselves, the only way that comes to my head is to convert somehow my computation problem to multirequest, so every request will have a part of job to do (maybe with help of JMS?). But, truly, I'm not sure if this is even possible to achieve (sending request to ourselfs :)). So can anybody tell me how I should deal such a problems in future (or it is possible at all to deal with it)?

**EDIT: Due to ask, I'm posting example:**

Let's assume that we have a problem that can be resolve by using heuristic, for example Genetic Algorithm. This algorithm can be evaluated in many threads, so we would like to use parallel programming. However, we need to make it web application because everything should be accesible form web browser and we want to have everything in one app (so the algorithm should be embedded to our web app).

Ok, I know that we can do this as standalone application and use JMX,WebServices or others to managed it remotely, but I would like to know if we could realize it as one web application.

Comment: Can you describe your scenario in more detail, like the type of problem you are trying to solve. That will be useful for SO users to help.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading in EE would infringe on other applications running in the container as pointed out in the other post. The easy solution is to use a separate JVM on another machine and access it with Remote Procedure Calls (RMI is an easy one.) That way you can do whatever you would like without restrictions.