# Using ExecutorService how to get the threadpool from the web container

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, weblogic-10.x, executorservice

I need to create a project in Java5 using Future technology to make several EJB/Web service calls.

I worked through the [tutorial](http://technology.amis.nl/2009/02/19/asynchronous-processing-in-java-applications-leveraging-those-multi-cores/) that explains the different ways to do it.

It looks like ExecutorService is the easiest as it manages the threads for you but all the examples I found on the web create the pool/size manually.

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

My program is running in a Web Logic container.

How do I instantiate the ExecutorService by using the existing Thread pool from the container?

Comment: Have you read [Using Threads in WebLogic Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13706/topics.htm)? It looks like a starting point.

Comment: I have been explicitly asked not to use Weblogic Workmanagers but to stick to Java ways of doing it. But we should be Java5 compatible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jboss Java EE container and an ExecutorService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932083/jboss-java-ee-container-and-an-executorservice)