# HornetQ queue consumer as a Thread inside Java EE 6 environment

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jms, hornetq

I need to consume messages from a JMS queue deployed on JBoss 7.2.
My consumer is particular in the sense that it needs to keep the processed message, in order to "chain it" with the next message : Mn = Mn-1 + Mn, before sending it to a DB.

I know MDB are stateless, so I can't use them for this specific use case.

I opted for a classic Java Thread, applying an endless loop inside its run method, and call queue recieve.

```
public void run() {
     // queue to listen to
     consumer = session.createConsumer(myQueue);
     // start
     con.start();
     while (true) {
        // listen ...
        ObjectMessage recievedObj = (ObjectMessage) consumer.receive();
        // do some work

        lastRecievedObj = recievedObj;
     }
}
```

The fact is that it's not recommended to handle threads in a Java EE environment (except for Java EE 7).

What do you think? Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Old school approach: put your receiver logic in some Servlet, which may start threads at it's discretion. Then invoke the EJB when all messages have arrived.

Comment: which EJB to invoke ?

Comment: Some application servers (IBM WebSphere, Oracle WebLogic) support CommonJ WorkManager in a way that you can do a JNDI lookup and get a managed thread from container.

Comment: Is this possible for JBoss 7.2 ? i'm affraid we have no choice but to use JBoss 7.2.

Comment: >`which may start threads at its discretion` - This is not entirely correct. The "don't use threading" recommendation indeed says "EJB", but at the time EJB was thought to be a kind of synonym for Java EE. So the recommendations were most likely intended to account for Servlets, EJBs, and all else there is in Java EE.

Comment: Can't you just `@Inject` an `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Singleton` EJB into your MDB to get the next counter value?

Comment: @Alexander Langer an MDB is a stateless EJB, it can't be ApplicationScoped nor Singleton

Comment: That's why you shall inject another bean that holds the global counter.

Comment: I will try this, thanks , but i don't have a good feeling, because this counter will be accessed by one or more MDB, i don't how it will react and if it's threadsafe

Comment: this didn't work. i think i really need to use Threads, because i want the number of threads  or worker configurable, and each thread or worker should keep the state (lastprocessedMsg).
Has any one already tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932083/jboss-java-ee-container-and-an-executorservice ??