# What is the best way to make simultaneous httpurlconnection calls in a Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, httpurlconnection, java-ee-6, executorservice

We have a requirement where we have to make four web service calls from our EJB. All these calls are independent of each other and should be made simultaneously.

Today we are using `ExecutorService` to make these calls. There is a timeout after which we shutdown the `ExecutorService` and check the responses.

I want to know if there is a better way to do the same?

P.S.
We use websphere 8.5.0 which is a Java EE 6 server. I found there is ManagedExecutorService in Java EE 7. Is there anything in Java EE 6?

Comment: A helpful pattern for doing this in EE6 is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932083/jboss-java-ee-container-and-an-executorservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using an asynchronous method on a Stateless Session Bean (with the @Asynchronous annotation)? This method would make the call to the web service and the app server (via the EJB pool) would be responsible for managing concurrency.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html