# Replacing Websphere's WorkManager in JBoss?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, migration, websphere, workmanagers

We're moving from Websphere to JBoss, but some of the code has dependencies on Websphere's WorkManager (com.ibm.websphere.asyncbeans.WorkManager). Has anyone dealt with this before and have recommendations on how to replace Websphere's WorkManager and what you'd replace it with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no Java EE standard for a WorkManager equivalent; however, [JSR-236](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236) (Concurrency Utilities for Java EE) may be back as a candidate for inclusion in [Java EE 7](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=342).

Until then, depending on how you are currently using the IBM async beans WorkManager and your specific use cases, you may have a few different options to consider -

- [CommonJ WorkManager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/commonj/commonj.html#wp1057962)
- [EJB 3.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=220) Timer Service
- [EJB 3.1](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=318) Asynchronous Beans
- [Servlet 3.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) Asynchronous Servlets

Answer (score -1):

You could probably checkout the Spring Framework's `WorkManager`.

Check this link out for more details : [Class WorkManagerTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jca/work/WorkManagerTaskExecutor.html)

Comment: link-only questions are frowned upon here.  by all means, explain the essential details of your link.