# How to get notified once my web application is successfully deployed in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, web-deployment, servletcontextlistener

I want to get notified once my web application is successfully deployed in Tomcat without any error/exception ?

I could write a servletContextListener but `contextInitialized()` method will be called just before
the web application is started which will not solve my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp=$(mktemp -t catalina.XXXXXXX) || exit 136
trap 'rm "$tmp"' 0
trap 'exit 255' 2 15
tail -n 200 catalina.out >"$tmp"
if grep -q error "$tmp"; then
    cat "$tmp"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements are simple, it's easy enough to just create a single thread / runnable in a ServletContextListener. Create and start the thread in contextInitialized() and shut it down in contextDestroyed(). . Use a ScheduledExecutorService created by Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(). The Runnable you pass to the Executor would read from a BlockingQueue.

Find more information at [Creating threads a Webapplication which is deployed in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406427/creating-threads-a-webapplication-which-is-deployed-in-tomcat)

Comment: hey gabhi, my requirement is to trigger something once my web app gets started without any error. not just deployed in tomcat. Hence I think contextInitialized() is not the place where I can say it is deployed without any error in catalina.out

Answer (score 0):

What about to add a servlet as the last to be loaded,

```
<load-on-startup>99</load-on-startup>
```

and on this servlet make a call to another servlet that would make your operation ?
like this you would make sure that the app is fully loaded, as the second servlet would respond.

Would be nice to have a singleton to save any exception that happen on the startup procedures, so you could be notified, or use to sanity check of the app.

cheers.

Comment: all servlets may load properly but there are several spring beans which also should load without error/exception. so I think your <load-on-startup> approach will not work for me.