# Management Beans and Threads

Tags: jakarta-ee

I know the EJB spec discourages starting threads and opening sockets in beans but do those same restrictions apply to Management Beans (annotated with org.jboss.annotation.ejb.Management)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, starting threads and opening sockets in Management Beans has the same issues as in Session Beans described here:

[Why is spawning threads in Java EE container discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533783/why-spawning-threads-in-java-ee-container-is-discouraged)

The root problem is that you are not letting the container manage the resources and it doesn't make a difference what type of managed bean you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respnonse and for the link to further information.