# How to setup a SonarQube Warning for parallel streams in a Java EE container?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8, sonarqube

My scenario: With Java 8 Stream API, developers have the possibility to process collection via Streams normal and parallel (using multiple threads). In a Java EE environment, this should be avoided → [Is it discouraged using Java 8 parallel streams inside a Java EE container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845699/is-it-discouraged-using-java-8-parallel-streams-inside-a-java-ee-container) Other sources:

> The current consensus among Java™ EE engineers is that parallelization
>   of bulk operations will revert to sequential processing in the EE
>   container.
>   http://coopsoft.com/ar/Calamity2Article.html

Will SonarQube provide a rule, or how could I setup a custom rule for that, to detect, warn or inform developers, that they shall not used parallel streams on a java ee application server, that runs under Java 8, hence code reviews are not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there isn't such a rule available. And no custom rules (based on regexp or something else) could be configured via the user interface.

But you could write your own java plugin with a set of custom java rules. A simple example (by SonarSource) is [available on github](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules). It looks quite simple to provide your own rule. May be it worth it.