# What advantage is there to using Spring @Async vs. CompleteableFuture directly?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

What's the advantage of using [Spring Async](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) vs. Just returning the `CompletableFuture` on your own?

Comment: Maybe [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533783/why-is-spawning-threads-in-java-ee-container-discouraged) will help you.

Comment: This might have made sense in pre java 8. But CompletableFuture by default forks onto the fork join pool.

Comment: You've got a managed environment. It is discouraged to spawn threads on your own, but if you have to, then you can use the `CompletableFuture` with an injected `ExecutorService` which should be managed by your container.

Comment: Offer it as an answer and let's if you get upvoted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your application is managed by the container. Since it's discouraged to spawn `Thread`s on you own, you can let the container inject a managed `Executor`.

```
@Service
class MyService {
  @Autowired
  private Executor executor;

  public CompletableFuture<?> compute() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> /* compute value */, executor);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 41):

There is no “*vs.*” between the two – these are complementary technologies:

- `CompletableFuture` provides a convenient way to chain different stages of asynchronous computation – with more flexibility than Spring's `ListenableFuture`;
- `@Async` provides convenient management of your background tasks and threads, with standard Spring configuration for your executor(s).

But both can be combined ([since Spring 4.2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13128)). Suppose you want to turn the following method into a background task returning a `CompletableFuture`:

```
public String compute() {
    // do something slow
    return "my result";
}
```

What you have to do:

- if not already done: configure your application with `@EnableAsync` and an `Executor` bean
- annotate the method with `@Async`
- wrap its result into `CompletableFuture.completedFuture()`

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> computeAsync() {
    // do something slow - no change to this part
    // note: no need to wrap your code in a lambda/method reference,
    //       no need to bother about executor handling
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("my result");
}
```

As you notice, you don't have to bother about submitting the background task to an executor: Spring takes care of that for you. You only have to wrap the result into into a completed `CompletableFuture` so that the signature matches what the caller expects.

In fact, this is equivalent to:

```
@Autowire
private Executor executor;

public CompletableFuture<String> computeAsync() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        // do something slow
        return "my result";
    }, executor);
}
```

but it removes the need to:

- inject the executor
- deal with the executor in a `supplyAsync()` call
- wrap the logic in a lambda (or extract it to a separate method)

Comment: I don’t see how this is a better way than the one in the accepted answer. There’s less magic there. What am I missing?

Comment: @BalázsNémeth, not sure which one you are refirring to with “_less magic there_”, but I assume it is the one in the accepted answer. Indeed if you don't like the _magic_, as usual the programmatic version will be better for you. However people usually consider declarative programming better, which is the case when using Spring's `@Async`. Of course, that involves some “_magic_” ;)

Comment: I see your point. @Async is a higher level concept. I should probably trust it but I somehow don't :)

Comment: @BalázsNémeth One thing I particularly appreciate with `@Async` is that you don't have to specify the executor, but you are still able to customize it through Spring's `@EnableAsync` configuration. With `supplyAsync()`, either you use the common F-J pool (probably not desirable), or you have to pass the executor parameter every time you use it.

Comment: One gotcha about `@Async` is if the method is called from within the same class, the call will not be async. It's only when it's called from a different class that spring gets to inject the proxied bean and intercept the call and submit it to a different thread. No such issue with `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` with explicit executor service (which can be wired in by spring).

Comment: Does anyone know why we use ```completedFuture``` method here and not ```supplyAsync( () -> "myResylt")``` ? Because it is not quite clear which one is preferable.

Comment: @privalou `supplyAsync()` would schedule your supplier for execution and make it run on a separate thread, which would be useless since there would actually be nothing to compute. In fact `completedFuture()` is the non-async equivalent, it’s just a convenient way to wrap a value in a `CompletableFuture`. `@Async` makes Spring deal with the whole async logic for you. I have add the equivalent code in the answer if you weren’t using `@Async`, hope this helps.

Comment: @DidierL: Does that mean, spring @Async overrides the behavior of Java8's [completedFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-) whose purpose is to return `CompletableFuture<T>` of an already computed result. So, Spring's @Async will resolve the code snippet i.e., "my result" and pass it to `supplyAysnc()` lambda? If yes why pass it to thread when result is already computed. Please clarify and correct me here if I am wrong

Comment: @srk Spring does not modify the implementation of your method or the `CompletableFuture` class. Instead, it will wrap the calls to your method such that they are executed asynchronously, and immediately return an uncompleted `CompletableFuture`. When your method returns, the result will be passed back to that future to make it available to the original caller.

Answer (score 2):

`@Async` is more save in a Spring App. Using `CompletableFuture` in a Spring Application can be dangerous. The Threads are not created by Spring and do not inherit from Spring own configured `ClassLoader`. This way, dynamic loading of classes can fail at runtime inside a `CompletableFuture` execution block. See [CompletableFuture / ForkJoinPool Set Class Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113207/completablefuture-forkjoinpool-set-class-loader).