# CompletableFuture VS @Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I am not good at English.

I use asynchronous methods.

**Option 1**

```java
public CompletableFuture<Integer> getDiscountPriceAsync(Integer price) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            log.info("supplyAsync");
            return (int)(price * 0.9);
        }, threadPoolTaskExecutor);
    }
```

**Option 2**

```java
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Integer> getDiscountPriceAsync(Integer price) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            log.info("supplyAsync");
            return (int)(price * 0.9);
        }, threadPoolTaskExecutor);
    }
```

I wonder what the difference is between using @Async and not using it.

I think the first Option1 provides enough asynchronous methods.
However, is it correct to use it like Option2?

Comment: Related: [What advantage is there to using Spring @Async vs. CompleteableFuture directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44685187/525036)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Option 2 is asynchronous done twice.

If you annotated a method withe @Async it will be executed by Spring asynchronously. So you don't need to use the ThreadPoolExecutor by yourself.

Instead you could write:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Integer> getDiscountPriceAsync(Integer price) {
    log.info("supplyAsync");

    return new AsyncResult<Integer>((int)(price * 0.9)); 
}
```

Read more about Async with Spring here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it. Thank you

Comment: To return CompleteFuture, I have to use the complete() method of AsyncResult.


-->  return new AsyncResult<>((int) (price * 0.9)).completable();

Comment: @EddyKim, you can also use `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture((int)(price * 0.9));`

Comment: I can update my answer but before: Do you really need a CompletableFuture? Wouldn't Future be good enough?

Comment: @DidierL I like your comment!