# CompletableFuture Transaction rollback

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future

Given this pieace of code:

```java
@Async
@Transactional
public CompletableFuture<Optional<Bundle>> newBundle(String name){
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    Bundle newBundle = bundleRepository.save(new Bundle(name));
    messageRepository.save(new Message("saved new bundle with name {}", name);
    return Optional.of(newBundle);
}).exceptionally(throwable -> {
    log.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(throwable);
);
}
```

So when the call to

`messageRepository.save(new Message("saved new bundle with name {}", name);` fails,

will there be a rollback of

`bundleRepository.save(new Bundle(name));`

Comment: No. As the transaction is for a different thread, both save calls run in a different tx. You will need to put that code in another method (both save calls) which itself is annotated with `@Transactional`.

Comment: You should not use `supplyAsync()` together with `@Async`, they both do the same thing. Just perform your computation within the method, and wrap the result in a `completableFuture()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685187/what-advantage-is-there-to-using-spring-async-vs-completeablefuture-directly/44723876#44723876 (this is independent from the `@Transactional` issue though)

Comment: @DidierL Interesting. I looked up the docu for completedFuture saying "Returns a new CompletableFuture that is already completed with the given value." So for me this means i have no advantage using it, because it will wait for the result (blocks). Can i rely on Spring doing the right thing?

Comment: Don’t you usually expect Spring to do the right thing?  More seriously, this just follows [Spring’s Getting Started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method) as well as [the `@Async` documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `@Transactional` annotation works by creating a proxy around the annotated method to manage the transaction. However, its effectiveness can depend on how and where the method is called, especially in asynchronous operations.

Given your code snippet, you're using `@Async` together with `@Transactional` on a method that returns a `CompletableFuture`.

Transactional Context: The `@Transactional` annotation creates a transactional context at the start of the method execution. Any operations that occur within this method are supposed to be part of this transactional context.

This means that these repository calls might not participate in the same transaction unless you explicitly configure method execution and transaction propagation to support this pattern.