# What is the best practice for starting threads or loading shared resources in a Java application server outside of Servlet invocation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, application-server

**Abstract Question**

What is the best way to load resources into memory that will be shared across servlets in a Java application server?

**What I am actually doing**

I want to create a daemon thread that monitors a queue. This queue could have objects added to it from servlet threads. The thread would wait until a set period of time and check the queue to see if it had items in it, if so then it would process them and remove them. This thread would need to be started somewhere at sometime. I was thinking that a servlet with only the init method implemented would work for this task or is there a better place to put startup code like this in an application server? Am I approaching the problem all wonky?

**Updates**

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532360/thread-in-app-server) and the accepted answer was to use the LifeCycle Listener. Is this a portable way of doing things or is my code going to be tied to a single application server. A bit more investigation led me to a find a few posts on message boards saying that I could do this in a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I usually start these kinds of worker threads indirectly from a Servlet using the method you describe (usually they exist inside some other object that does the queue extraction and controls the processing).

For pulling objects off the thread, you don't need to do it based on time, you could have your thread wait() on the queue object and when an object is put onto the queue by some other thread, that thread would call notify() on the queue to release the watching 'worker' thread.

Google 'java worker thread wait notify' for many examples.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on wait/notify.